# Can you graph a time-series with continuously changing entries?

Tags: sql, database, graph, charts, time-series

How do I graphically represent a time-series where entries of this graph change over time?

For example I have a database of cities and their corresponding average temperature per day. I want a graphical representation of the ten hottest cities per day, and how they change over time. Do new cities appear on this list? Which cities drop out of this list?

Normally 6/10 of these cities will always be on the “top ten hottest” list, but sometimes a particular entry may spike up and join the top ten list. Is there a way to analyze the top ten list and compare it over time?

I’m having trouble thinking of a way to graph this because of the varying entries.

Answer (score 1):

Your x-axis is day, but what's on the y-axis? Temperature? If so, you can have a different series (may be called something else depending on your charting package) for each city, and just add points to the series when it is one of the top ten for that day. This may require you to do some pre-processing on your data, in order to figure out which set of cities makes the top-ten list over your time frame.

Answer (score 0):

In one of our widget implementations we have a setting for the time chart to display only top-n series, ranked by avg or last value. This was done to remove clutter by hiding too many unimportant series from the chart.

In your case why not show a bar for each period where the bar would contain top-N series for the period and a grey area for the remainder?